# What are the levers on my washing machine hose connection fittings?

Tags: hose

In the picture below, can someone identify the silver grooved items with rounded ends between the hose connections.  If they are shut-off valves, they do not move with normal force (or really at all).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Those knobs are indeed quarter turn shut off valves. They have probably not been turned in years and have buildup of mineral deposits inside or some other type of corrosion.

The shutoff valves are there to allow it to be easy to attach / replace the washer water hoses.

Before trying to see if you can free them up you will have to figure out how to turn off the water supply up stream from where these are located. You may be having to replace the whole water hammer arrester assemblies to get valves that will work.

Note that it is quite common that those in wall laundry hose hookup boxe units having crappy shutoff valves. The ones in my house are similar but have a simple round turn knob on the top and are very difficult to turn after sitting for a long time.

Comment: Thanks.  The water upstream has already been shut-off.  Frankly, I'm most interested in moving the levers just to allow more space for pliers.  As it is, it will be nearly impossible to get plier jaws on the hose connections unless I go straight on.

Comment: I totally agree (+1) but would suggest that in addition to allowing shut-off for hose replacement, they are there for easy flood-risk reduction. I have similar valves and turn them off every time I leave for vacation, I have seen **so many** swollen/burst washing machine hoses in my life. Added bonus is that exercising the valves a few times annually helps keep them operating.

Comment: And yes, I turn off the stop-valves to the kitchen and bath faucets too... sigh. Obsessive/compulsive behavior, I know... my wife says so too (all the time)