# Which position is open with these laundry shutoff valves?

Tags: plumbing, hose

In which direction does on turn the water ON versus OFF for the shown washing hose levers? E.G., is UP on or off? Is DOWN on or off?
[image]

Comment: why are you using a picture from 5 years ago?  if this is your washing machine, why don't you already know the answer?  have you tried moving them?

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/135970/what-are-the-levers-on-my-washing-machine-hose-connection-fittings

i would assume up is off and toward the camera is on, but just move them and find out

Comment: Place one up and one down, see which water(hot/cold) you get.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume if the handle is inline with the copper pipe then it is open and if at 90 degrees then it is closed. So, from the position shown I suggest they are closed.

However, you can check if the machine gets water by running a simple rinse cycle, if it does not get water then change the handle position... Or run the hoses into a bucket.

I have used many valves and the normal position is inline with the pipe then open... Unless someone changes the handle due to a tight position etc.

Comment: Copper pipe = water hammer arrestor?